# density gamma in Rcpp and R

Tags: r, rcpp, gamma

I am evaluating the density of a gamma distribution with different supports.. Here is my Rcpp code..

```
// [[Rcpp::export]] 
NumericVector fdensv(NumericVector w, NumericMatrix pard){
nj = w.size();
NumericVector out(nj);
for (int j=0;j<nj;j++){
    out[j] = R::dgamma(log(w[j]),pard(0,j),pard(1,j),0);
}
return out;
}

sourceCpp("test2.cpp")
```

Now testing the code

```
nj = 200
dr = exp(rgamma(nj,2,3))
pr = matrix(runif(400*2,2,4),2,200)
gg = fdensv(dr,pr)

gg2 = NULL
for (i in 1:nj)
 {
 gg2[i] = dgamma(log(dr[i]),pr[1,i],pr[2,i])
  }

cbind(gg,gg2)
all.equal(gg,gg2)
```

I obtain that "Mean relative difference: 32.77"... Any idea where this discrepancy is coming from? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're being bitten by the fact that R uses a different parameterization at the R level, and C level, for the `gamma` functions. You will observe equal results if you change the `dgamma` call to

```
R::dgamma(log(w[j]), pard(0,j), 1/pard(1,j), 0);
```

This is briefly discussed in [R-exts 6.7.1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Distribution-functions) -- note that it takes `scale` and not `rate`.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual issue. Been discussed here before too, and I think on rcpp-devel as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too complicated. Start simpler:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]] 
double mydgamma(double a, double b, double c, int d) {
  return R::dgamma(a, b, c, d);
}
```

and see the header about the shape and rate parameter.

Then

```
R> mydgamma(0.5, 1, 1, 0)
[1] 0.606531
R> dgamma(0.5,1)
[1] 0.606531
R>
```

or

```
R> mydgamma(0.25, 0.5, 1, 0)
[1] 0.878783
R> dgamma(0.25,0.5)
[1] 0.878783
R>
```